# IndexError: list index out of range i am not reading files and my list does not seem to be out of range

Tags: python

I was programming a project of secret messages which uses a few lists and appends. To my understanding, I don't think that any of my lists are out of range so I am very confused on why I am getting this error. Here is my code.

```
from tkinter import Tk, messagebox, simpledialog



def is_even(number):
    return number % 2 == 0


def get_even_letters(message):
    even_letters = []
    for counter in range(0, len(message)):
        if is_even(counter):
            even_letters.append(message[counter])
            return even_letters



def get_odd_letters(message):
    odd_letters = []
    for counter in range(0, len(message)):
        if not is_even(counter):
            odd_letters.append(message[counter])
            return odd_letters
def swap_letters(message):
    letter_list = []
    if not is_even(len(message)):
        message = message + 'x'
    even_letters = get_even_letters(message)
    odd_letters = get_odd_letters(message)
    for counter in range(0, int(len(message)/2)):
        letter_list.append(odd_letters[counter])
        letter_list.append(even_letters[counter])
    new_message = ''.join(letter_list)
    return new_message


def get_task():
    task = simpledialog.askstring('Task', 'Do you want to encrypt or decrypt?')
    return task
def get_message():
    message = simpledialog.askstring('Message', 'Enter the secret message: ')
    return message


root = Tk()
root.withdraw()

while True:
    task = get_task()
    if task == 'encrypt':
        message = get_message()
        encrypted = swap_letters(message)
        messagebox.showinfo('Ciphertext of the secret message: ', encrypted)
    elif task == 'decrypt':
        message = get_message()
        decrypted = swap_letters(message)
        messagebox.showinfo('Plaintext of the secret message: ', decrypted)
    else:
        break
root.mainloop()
```

Here is my error code:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Osprey/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/secret_messages.py", line 52, in 
    encrypted = swap_letters(message)
  File "C:/Users/Osprey/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/secret_messages.py", line 31, in swap_letters
    letter_list.append(odd_letters[counter])
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: `"I don't think that any of my lists are out of range"` Obviously `odd_letters` is, whether you think that or not.

Comment: what do you mean

Comment: Read the error that you receive very carefully. It tells you exactly where the problem is

Comment: well duh, I mean how/why is out of range?

Comment: and how to fix it

Comment: It's called debugging and it's your job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so I was messing around with the code and when I did this:

```
def get_message():
    message = simpledialog.askstring('Message', 'Enter the secret message: ')
    return str(message)
```

it worked!!!

Answer (score 1):

It seems you indented return of your functions earlier than you should.

In:

```
for counter in range(0, len(message)):
    if not is_even(counter):
        odd_letters.append(message[counter])
        return odd_letters
```

The `return odd_letters` will activate after the `append`, when your `if` condition is met.

What that means is that, as soon as your function finds a number that isn't even, it will append to the odd_letters and will return a list with only that number, since you returned it too early. That's why you get an `IndexError`, your list only has one item, so it will only accept it in case you only query it for index `0`.

To fix it, just remove 4 spaces. The other function has the same problem.

Comment: Are u saying I should remove the four spaces that exist before the "return odd_letters" line and "return even_letters" line? cause if so I tried that and it didn't work.